# Laravel 5 Saving the Selected input from a Form::Select

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, foreign-keys

I a struggling to save the chosen information from my selection box. I get the message:

> "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clientpad_notes`.`notebooks`, CONSTRAINT `notebooks_contact_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `notebooks` (`name`, `contact_id`, `note_description`, `note_body`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (assddsaasdadasasd, 3, saS,
>
> ssss
>
> , 2, 2018-03-03 19:18:51, 2018-03-03 19:18:51)

My problem is that I am bringing in information to notes create page from contacts table. So I have my tables linked with authentication with user_id and inside the notes tables I have contacts_id. I am aiming to select and save a contact name fetching it by it's id, when creating a new note. It is possible I have been going around doing this in a wrong way, I am a beginner at Laravel so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my notes controllers and create a note page.

**NotesController.php**

public function create()
    {

```
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $contacts = Contact::find($user->contacts)->pluck('fullName');
    return view('notebooks.create')->with('contacts', $contacts)->with('user', $user);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'name' => 'required',
        'contact_id' => 'required',
        'note_description' => 'required',
        'note_body' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Create a note
    $notebook = new Notebook;
    $notebook->name = $request->input('name');
    $notebook->contact_id = $request->input('contact_id');
    $notebook->note_description = $request->input('note_description');
    $notebook->note_body = $request->input('note_body');
    $notebook->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //currently logged in user show their notes
    $notebook->save();

    return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Your Note Was Created');
}
```

**create.blade.php**

```
                <div class="col-6 col-sm-3">
                        {{Form::label('contact_id', 'Choose your Contact')}}
                        {{Form::select('contact_id', $user->contacts->pluck('fullName'), $contacts, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}

                </div>
            </div>
```

In the database which saved notes I have this:

```
Schema::create('notebooks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('contact_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->mediumText('note_description');
        $table->mediumText('note_body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: do you have record with id of `3` in `contacts` table ?

Comment: no I actually dont. I deleted it at one stage when testing this. Is it important?

Comment: is not it ?  you are referencing contact_id to contacts table but there is no such id

Comment: Wow i did not realise that's what it did. I am trying to make sure that whatever the contact_id of the selected contact from the select form is, it saves into the database. I am not sure where I did what you said. I am very new at this and to be honest I followed many videos to lead me to what you are seeing above.

Comment: You are doing well, good luck

Comment: Can you specify which laravel version you are using? Since laravel 5 does not has the form helper anymore. Or in case, which package you are using. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO after lots of searching I found a solution. In Create I had to use mapping:

```
public function create(Contact $contact)
{

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $contacts = $user->contacts->mapWithKeys(function($contact){
        return [$contact->id => $contact->fullName];
    });
    // dd ($contacts);
    return view('notebooks.create')->with('contacts', $contacts)->with('user', $user);
}
```

Then in Select I just called for this:

```
   {{Form::label('contact_id', 'Choose your Contact')}}
   {{Form::select('contact_id', $contacts, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Works like a charm, in case anyone else finds this useful

Answer (score 0):

You made  small mistake when working with Id's from other tables. You should check if the ID actually exists in the target table.

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required',
    'contact_id' => 'required|exists:contacts', //This will validate that the contact ID actually exists.
    'note_description' => 'required',
    'note_body' => 'required',
]);

//Create a note
$notebook = new Notebook;
$notebook->name = $request->input('name');
$notebook->contact_id = $request->input('contact_id');
$notebook->note_description = $request->input('note_description');
$notebook->note_body = $request->input('note_body');
$notebook->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //currently logged in user show their notes
$notebook->save();
```

[Laravel validation#rule-exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-exists)

## Update

```
$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required',
    'contact_id' => 'required|exists:contacts,id', //check contacts table, for column ID
    'note_description' => 'required',
    'note_body' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: So I got this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'contact_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `contacts` where `contact_id` = 1)" Does that mean the id wasn't found.

Comment: Its very likely I done my code wrong. I am trying to save the contact from a select box into my database, but saving it by the id of the name chosen. Maybe I am misunderstanding what my code is actually doing?Like the guy above said my code is looking for id 3? I am not sure how its doing that. Sorry for the trouble, I really am new at this

Comment: that didnt work either. It is telling me the contacts_id column is unknown even thought it is there in the table. When I added updated code it tells me id is unknown in table. Thanks though

Comment: @MonikaZygadlo Can you confirm you are using laravel 5 btw? Since laravel 5 removed the form helper and you seem to be using it anyway.